# Merge in between dates

Tags: r

I have the following 2 dataframes

```
Data = data.frame(Name = c("Steve", "Sephiroth", "Hero"),
                  Date = c("03/01/2019", "01/09/2017", "06/07/2018"))

Map = data.frame(Name = c("Steve",  "Steve",    "Steve" ,"Sephiroth",   "Sephiroth" ,"Sephiroth",   "Hero", "Hero", "Hero"),
                 Class = c("1A",    "2B"    ,"3A",  "1E",   "2C",   "3E",   "1A",   "2D"    ,"3A"),
                 StartDate = c("01/01/2017" ,"01/01/2018"   ,"01/01/2019"   ,"01/01/2017"   ,"01/01/2018"   ,"01/01/2019"   ,"01/01/2017",  "01/01/2018",   "01/01/2019"),
                 EndDate = c("31/12/2017",  "31/12/2018",   "31/12/2019",   "31/12/2017",   "31/12/2018",   "31/12/2019",   "31/12/2017",   "31/12/2018",   "31/12/2019"))
```

I want the create a new dataframe by merging them according to their dates. If the "Date" falls in between "StartDate" and "EndDate", it should take the Class accordingly. For Example, Steve's date is 03/01/2019, so it should return 3A. I have seen couple other solutions on stackoverflow but they dont seem to be very elegant, is there any way for me to fit everything into a couple of lines using similar code?

```
Merged = merge(x = Data, y = Map, by = "Name", all.x = TRUE)
```

This code will return me every row that exists in Map dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) sqldf** Using the data in the Note at the end (same as in question except we changed the data frame names and fixed the formatting) convert the date columns to Date class and then at that point we have a one statement solution performing a left join on the indicated complex condition:

```
library(sqldf)

fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
Data2 <- transform(Data1, Date = as.Date(Date, fmt))
Map2 <- transform(Map1, 
  StartDate = as.Date(StartDate, fmt),
  EndDate = as.Date(EndDate, fmt)
)

sqldf("select * 
  from Data2 d
  left join Map2 m on d.Name = m.Name and d.Date between m.StartDate and m.EndDate")
```

giving:

```
       Name       Date      Name Class  StartDate    EndDate
1     Steve 2019-01-03     Steve    3A 2019-01-01 2019-12-31
2 Sephiroth 2017-09-01 Sephiroth    1E 2017-01-01 2017-12-31
3      Hero 2018-07-06      Hero    2D 2018-01-01 2018-12-31
```

**2) base**  If we can assume that the ranges in Map1 are always a calendar year (which is the case for the data in the question) then we can reduce the dates to years and `merge` on `Name` and `year` (which need not be specified since they are the only common column names).  The `all.x=TRUE` specifies a left join and ensures that any row in `Data3` that has no match in `Map3` is still included in the output.  If we did not need this or if we knew that there was a match for every row (which is the case in the data shown in the question) we could optionally omit this argument.  This approach is less general than (1) due to the full year assumption but uses no packages and is quite short.

```
Data3 <- transform(Data1, year = sub(".*/", "", Date))
Map3 <- transform(Map1, year = sub(".*/", "", StartDate))
merge(Data3, Map3, all.x = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
       Name year       Date Class  StartDate    EndDate
1      Hero 2018 06/07/2018    2D 01/01/2018 31/12/2018
2 Sephiroth 2017 01/09/2017    1E 01/01/2017 31/12/2017
3     Steve 2019 03/01/2019    3A 01/01/2019 31/12/2019
```

**If we can't make the full year assumption** then left join on `Name` and `subset` the result down.  We will use `Data2` and `Map2` from (1).

```
s <- subset(merge(Data2, Map2, all.x = TRUE), Date >= StartDate & Date <= EndDate)
merge(Data2, s, all.x = TRUE)  # add unmatched rows
```

giving:

```
       Name       Date Class  StartDate    EndDate
2      Hero 2018-07-06    2D 2018-01-01 2018-12-31
4 Sephiroth 2017-09-01    1E 2017-01-01 2017-12-31
9     Steve 2019-01-03    3A 2019-01-01 2019-12-31
```

giving:

### Note

```
Data1 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Steve", "Sephiroth", "Hero"),
  Date = c("03/01/2019", "01/09/2017", "06/07/2018")
)

Map1 <- data.frame(
   Name = c("Steve",  "Steve",    "Steve" ,"Sephiroth", "Sephiroth", 
     "Sephiroth",   "Hero", "Hero", "Hero"),
   Class = c("1A" ,"2B", "3A", "1E", "2C", "3E", "1A", "2D", "3A"),
   StartDate = c("01/01/2017" ,"01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2017",
    "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019","01/01/2017",  "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019"),
   EndDate = c("31/12/2017",  "31/12/2018", "31/12/2019", "31/12/2017", 
     "31/12/2018", "31/12/2019", "31/12/2017", "31/12/2018", "31/12/2019")
)
```

### Note 2

Here is a run showing output based on changing the year for Steve to 2022.

```
Data1 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Steve", "Sephiroth", "Hero"),
  Date = c("03/01/2022", "01/09/2017", "06/07/2018")
)

Map1 <- data.frame(
   Name = c("Steve",  "Steve",    "Steve" ,"Sephiroth", "Sephiroth", 
     "Sephiroth",   "Hero", "Hero", "Hero"),
   Class = c("1A" ,"2B", "3A", "1E", "2C", "3E", "1A", "2D", "3A"),
   StartDate = c("01/01/2017" ,"01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2017",
    "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019","01/01/2017",  "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019"),
   EndDate = c("31/12/2017",  "31/12/2018", "31/12/2019", "31/12/2017", 
     "31/12/2018", "31/12/2019", "31/12/2017", "31/12/2018", "31/12/2019")
)

fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
Data2 <- transform(Data1, Date = as.Date(Date, fmt))
Map2 <- transform(Map1, 
  StartDate = as.Date(StartDate, fmt),
  EndDate = as.Date(EndDate, fmt)
)

s <- subset(merge(Data2, Map2, all.x = TRUE), Date >= StartDate & Date <= EndDate)
merge(Data2, s, all.x = TRUE)  # add unmatched rows
```

giving:

```
       Name       Date Class  StartDate    EndDate
1      Hero 2018-07-06    2D 2018-01-01 2018-12-31
2 Sephiroth 2017-09-01    1E 2017-01-01 2017-12-31
3     Steve 2022-01-03  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I actually have another dataset on my working device and this isnt the answer that I am looking for. The date range may not necessarily be one year, it could be multiple years. The StartDate and EndDate could also be random and there will also be random breaks in between them. I also don't have the package sqldf installed because I am working offline due to security reasons. When the Date does not fall into any of the date range, it should return as "NA"

Comment: Hi, I have tried the script again and it works, just one small issue this time. Let's say I changed Steve's date to 03/01/2022 instead and the Map's StartDate and EndDate all remain the same. When I do the merge, it does not return me Steve's row. I would want the row to return Steve's name but with the class labeled as NA

Comment: Good point. Have fixed (2).  (1) already did this.

Comment: One last thing, the StartDate and EndDate may not necessarily be a full calendar year, the student may change class half way through the year so creating a "year" column may not be the most accurate. So I would think that using Data2 and Map2 would be more accurate. The script you have provided does not show unmatched rows even though there is "all.x = TRUE". Is there a way to show unmatched rows?

Comment: You need to use the code after the bold text that says: **If we can't make the full year assumption**  That code does not assume a full year, it does not output a year column and it does include all rows from Data.

Comment: Hi I am aware that I am supposed to be using the code after the bold text, I changed Steve's date to 03/01/2022 but when I run the code, it only returns me rows for Sephiroth and Hero

Comment: This is really odd, it is still not showing for me. This will do for me. Thank you for all your patience.

Comment: Maybe your R session got messed up somehow. Exit R and then start a fresh R session.  Make sure no packages are loaded.  Do not just detach your packages. Start a fresh session. Then copy and paste the code in Note 2.  Also check the version of R you are using -- it is shown when you start the session.  I am using "R version 4.0.3 Patched (2020-12-21 r79672)"

Answer (score 2):

It's effectively a rolling join. I'd do this with `data.table` in one line. (Although you need to convert to `data.table` and make those dates actual dates first.

```
library(data.table); setDT(Map); setDT(Data)
Map[, StartDate := lubridate::dmy(StartDate)]
Data[, Date := lubridate::dmy(Date)]

Data[, Class := Map[Data, Class, on = c('Name', 'StartDate' = 'Date'), roll = TRUE]]
Data
#>         Name       Date Class
#> 1:     Steve 2019-01-03    3A
#> 2: Sephiroth 2017-09-01    1E
#> 3:      Hero 2018-07-06    2D
```

Edit:
I'm assuming that the EndDate is always one day before the next StartDate. If that's not true you'll have to be more careful. Also if there is a Date after the last EndDate it'll just give you the Class for the last StartDate. Again if you don't want that perhaps you'd add another row to Map to catch those cases and assign NA to the Class there.

Here's a more general version along the same lines that accounts for missing periods,

```
library(data.table); setDT(Map); setDT(Data)
Map[, StartDate := lubridate::dmy(StartDate)]
Map[, EndDate := lubridate::dmy(EndDate)]
Data[, Date := lubridate::dmy(Date)]

Map2 <- rbind(
  Map[, .(Name, Date = StartDate, Class)],
  Map[, .(Name, Date = EndDate+1, Class = NA_character_)]
)
Map2 <- Map2[!duplicated(Map2[, .(Name, Date)])]

Data[, Class := Map2[Data, Class, on = c('Name', 'Date'), roll = TRUE]]
Data
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this works! But I was wondering; you converted the StartDate and Date but not EndDate, is converting EndDate not required?

Comment: Just to add on, in the actual dataset that I am working with, the EndDate may not necessary be one day after the StartDate and if the "Date" does not fall into any of the date ranges, it should return NA.